# How to print the online txt file line by line?

Tags: python

My codes are listed as following:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

headers = {'User-Agent':
                       '''Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
                       AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
                       Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'''}

url = 'https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt'

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)

fname = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode()

for line in fname:
    print(line)
```

The output is not line by line, but characters? How can I print the file line by line? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try using split by newline for your string.

```
for line in fname.split('\n'):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem has been settled. Could you please explain that why the page source code looks line by line, but the output is one character a time?

Comment: In python, strings are stored in the form of streams of char, kind of like an array format. So each index can hold a character. That's the reason for your output. So it considered printing  one index item a time.

Comment: Thank you! Then we open a txt file directly, we could print the contents line by line. Like these codes: fname = input('Enter file name: ')
if (len(fname) < 1): fname = 'https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt'
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: '): continue
    pieces = line.split()
    email = pieces[1]  Is this because 'fh'  a handle?

Comment: Yes. And also you need to check if the file exists using import os commands if you have a process along with the length of the file string.

Comment: This will work but you should know that it will have an overhead (memory and performance) due to `split()`. If the text is short, no worries.

Comment: Thank you! Then how to solve the problem efficiently if the text is quite long?

Answer (score 0):

Your `read()` is reading the text into a string.

```py
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

headers = {'User-Agent':
                       '''Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
                       AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
                       Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'''}

url = 'https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt'

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)

fname = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
count = 0
for line in fname:
    count += 1
    print(count)
    print(line.decode())
```

Which Yields:

```py
1
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008

2
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>

3
Received: from murder (mail.umich.edu [141.211.14.90])

4
by frankenstein.mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.3.8) with LMTPA;

5     
Sat, 05 Jan 2008 09:14:16 -0500

6
X-Sieve: CMU Sieve 2.3

7
Received: from murder ([unix socket])

8
by mail.umich.edu (Cyrus v2.2.12) with LMTPA;

9
Sat, 05 Jan 2008 09:14:16 -0500

10
Received: from holes.mr.itd.umich.edu (holes.mr.itd.umich.edu [141.211.14.79])
...
```